# Installing IPython in emacs

Tags: python, emacs, ipython, python-mode

My apologies if this is a repost. I couldn't find a similar one in the questions.

I am trying to set up emacs as my python IDE with IPython in it. Basically follow this http://www.jesshamrick.com/2012/09/18/emacs-as-a-python-ide/

The version of python in my emacs shell is 2.7.5 whereas the one in terminal 2.7.6. However typing ipython in to the emacs shell shows ipython is not installed, but I was able to install ipython to the terminal.

I would like to know how to install the ipython plugin to the .emacs file. When you say install, does it mean copy the files and put it there ? If yes, I have done this. However when I try to run a python program, it shows "Searching for program: No such file or directory, ipython. Thanks in advance for the help.

[image: Screenshot of error from emacs]

Comment: Can you show the exact error message that emacs gives you?

Comment: See if http://stackoverflow.com/a/17817119/1350992 helps.

Comment: See emacs-ipython project - https://github.com/burakbayramli/emacs-ipython - you can do python in markdown or latex buffers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that your emacs cannot find ipython. You may need to set `PATH` environment variable, but for now, I think this works...

In your terminal do `which ipython`, and you will get your ipython executable path. Then in your .emacs file, change `"ipython"` in the following line to whatever the absolute path that you get.

```
(setq-default py-shell-name "ipython")
```