# Setting up Emacs to work with python/IPython

Tags: python, emacs, ipython

I have been coding for a while using R and RStudio but recently I started to dig into python. It is fair to say that I am new to python, but moreover, new to editing the emacs .init file (`.emacs`) in detail.  I am trying to set and understand the interplay between `python` and `emacs`, mainly IPython, since I suspect that I am going to be heavily using IPython in the near future.

At the beginning, my intention was only to be able to use `.emacs` to edit some code and then, if necessary, copy and paste into IPython. At that stage, the part of my `.emacs` file dedicated to `python` was:

```
;; Enable python
(add-to-list 'load-path "/sw/lib/python-mode-1.0")
(setq auto-mode-alist
      (cons '("\\.py$" . python-mode) auto-mode-alist))
(setq interpreter-mode-alist
      (cons '("python" . python-mode)
        interpreter-mode-alist))
(autoload 'python-mode "python-mode" "Python editing mode." t)
```

I loaded `/sw/lib/python-mode-1.0`, which comes from installing `fink` a while ago, because is the only directory in which I found a python-mode.el file. At that time seemed the only sequence of commands that worked (I have the intuition that half of it is not needed(?)).

The I learned that you could send commands from `.emacs` to Python/IPython. I typed: `M-x python-mode` , and then `M-x py-shell` to work with "normal-python" and it worked. Here I would have to ask the 1st question.

1- Every time I run a command I obtain the message:

```
`## working on region in file /var/folders/bd/f2194wl90rg38c8jqc12m47m0000gn/T/python-13120iJs.py..`
```

How do I avoid obtaining this message (every time!). This question is less important than the second one below.

Then, based on this post: [How to open IPython interpreter in emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17817019/how-to-open-ipython-interpreter-in-emacs) I typed this into my `.emacs` file:

```
(when (executable-find "ipython")
  (setq
   python-shell-interpreter "ipython"
   python-shell-interpreter-args ""
   python-shell-prompt-regexp "In \\[[0-9]+\\]: "
   python-shell-prompt-output-regexp "Out\\[[0-9]+\\]: "
   python-shell-completion-setup-code
   "from IPython.core.completerlib import module_completion"
   python-shell-completion-module-string-code
   "';'.join(module_completion('''%s'''))\n"
   python-shell-completion-string-code
   "';'.join(get_ipython().Completer.all_completions('''%s'''))\n"))
```

This, effectively, allows me to use IPython by typing: `M-x run-python`. However, when I try `C-c C-c` I obtain the error message : `C-c C-c is undefined`. (same for `C-c |` , also undefined)

At this stage, I have these two "chunks" of python-set-up lines in my `.emacs` file and nothing seems to work properly. I have looked in the web and found this: http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/1/config/editors.html ,  so I also tried to type: `(require 'ipython)` and it did not work either. It says that `file ipython is not found`. Therefore, the 2nd and most important question in this post is:

2- Can someone help me to do a clean set up of IPython in Emacs? (I do not mind if I have to remove all the set up lines so far. I simply want to be able to work efficiently using Emacs+IPython)

I am using a Mac 10.9.5. Emacs  version is 24.4. Python 2.7.8. And in case is of any use, I installed python using anaconda:

```
>which python
/anaconda/bin/python

>which ipython
/anaconda/bin/ipython
```

and emacs with macports, and is "aliased":

```
 >which emacs 
 emacs:   aliased to open -a /Applications/MacPorts/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are different python-mode's in parallel - nothing wrong so far, however the last loaded takes the keymap and also the menu. The keys missing are from python-mode.el - consult the menu "Python" in this case, which should indicate the other ones.

BTW <kbd>py- TAB</kbd> displays available commands from python-mode.el, while

<kbd>python- TAB</kbd> likewise from shipped python.el

WRT the first question, messaging: in most cases code isn't sent to interpreter-shell, but stored in a temporary file, whose result you'll see. The reason are coding issues - otherwise several bugs show up. So this message delivers good news - and is useful for debugging/tweaking.

Maybe consider a bug-report at https://bugs.launchpad.net/python-mode

Comment: Hi Andreas, thanks. Just a couple of things. Regarding to my question 1, do you mean that the message is a good thing, but still IS a bug to be reported at https://bugs.launchpad.net/python-mode? And secondly, when I type `M-x py-TAB` (if this is what you mean) the only completion possible is `python-mode`. In any case, for now, everything seems to work all right :) . Thanks again.

Comment: @Javier If  M-x py-TAB doesn't display the commands, python-mode.el isn't loaded. BTW bug-reporting was indicated for completeness only - cheers.

Comment: Hi Andreas.Yeah sorry, you are right. Yesterday when I wrote I did not realized that Python-mode was not on. I think it works for now (we'll see). Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Nonetheless, as I see now, when I type `M-x py-TAB` on an emacs window goes directly into `python-mode`. Now if I type again `M-x py-TAB` goes into `python-...`  with lots of different completions. I am guessing I am not loading python-mode.el, correct?

Comment: Andreas, problem solved, effectively python mode was not loaded. THANKS!

Comment: By the way, just realized that I am using your maintained python-mode.el file, fantastic! :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you start with using Emacs with no special configuration: Emacs-24.4 should just work out of the box for Python/IPython.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a plug-in for Emacs that allows interfacing with ipython while in Markdown or TeX buffer. While editing Python code you press a key, the region with Python code is sent over to ipython and its results are displayed right underneath as verbatim output. If there is a plt.show() call, it is converted into a plt.savefig(..) and the image reference is included in Markdown or TeX.

[emacs-ipython](https://github.com/burakbayramli/emacs-ipython)