# Emacs lisp code to open lots of multi-terminals

Tags: emacs, elisp

When I start working on my project, I need to run lots of processes. Currently, I have to launch each process in a manual way:

```
M-x multi-term RET
M-x rename-buffer RET *some-name* RET
cd ~/foo/bar/
python ./task.py
```

How to write a code on Emacs lisp that does the following steps:

- opens new multi-term buffer;
- renames it (I know the title I'd like to hardcode it for each process);
- runs one or two commands inside terminal

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17817119/1350992

Comment: This isn't a comprehensive answer, so I'll add it as a comment. You might be interested in the [`prodigy.el` package](https://github.com/rejeep/prodigy.el), a tool to "manage external services from within Emacs".

Comment: Yeah, prodigy.el seams exactly what I meant! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can start from this template:

```
(defun python-erica ()
  (interactive)
  (let* ((default-directory "~/")
         (proc (get-buffer-process
                (ansi-term "/usr/bin/ipython" "erica"))))
    (term-send-string
     proc
     (concat "import sys\n"))))
```

You can change:

- function name
- default dir
- python executable
- term buffer name
- initial commands